# Oracle Stored Procedure not loading data as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

In testing, I did the following (which worked):

```
create table testdata as select * from sometable;

create procedure testload as begin
delete from testdata;
insert into testdata select * from sometable;
end;
```

I've used the same structure for a more complex query. If I run "insert into testdata select [new query]", it will load the data into the table. However, when I created a new stored procedure using the new query, it will execute, but won't actually load data.

Note that this query was handed off to me, I didn't write it myself. The results have been validated, so while I appreciate any and all advice on how to clean up the code, I'm primarily interested in getting the stored procedure up and running with the code as close to what is below as possible.

```
select 
CLAIM_ID
,INTERNAL_ID
,line
,VENDOR_GROUP 
,case when (CLAIM_FORMAT_RULE+ POS_RULE + POS_TYPE_RULE+ POS_CODE_RULE+ MODIFIERS_RULE+ BILL_TYPE_RULE+ ATTENDING_PROV_RULE+ REFERRING_PROV_RULE) = 8 then 'Y' else 'N' end AUTH_FLAG
from 
(
SELECT         
AP.CLAIM_ID
,CLM1.INTERNAL_ID
, px.line
, DAT.VENDOR_GROUP

,MAX(CASE WHEN DAT.FORMAT_C IS NULL THEN 1  WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(AP.CLAIM_FORMAT_C,1,'CMS'),2,'UB') = UPPER(DAT.FORMAT_C) THEN 1 else 0 END) AS CLAIM_FORMAT_RULE     
,MAX(CASE WHEN DAT.POS_ID IS NULL THEN 1  WHEN EAF.INTERNAL_ID = DAT.POS_ID THEN 1  else 0 end ) AS POS_RULE        
,MAX(CASE WHEN DAT.POS_TYPE_C IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN NVL(PX.POS_TYPE_C,0) NOT IN (20,23) THEN 1 WHEN CAST(PX.POS_TYPE_C AS VARCHAR(10)) = DAT.POS_TYPE_C THEN 1 else 0 END) AS POS_TYPE_RULE               
,MAX(CASE WHEN DAT.PROC_CODE IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN DAT.PROC_CODE LIKE '%-%' AND EAP.PROC_CODE BETWEEN STRTOK(DAT.PROC_CODE,'-',1) AND STRTOK(DAT.PROC_CODE,'-',2) THEN 1 WHEN EAP.PROC_CODE = DAT.PROC_CODE THEN 1 else 0 END) AS POS_CODE_RULE             
,MAX(CASE WHEN DAT.MODIFIER IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN DAT.MODIFIER = PX.MODIFIERS THEN 1 else 0 END)  AS MODIFIERS_RULE              
,MAX(CASE WHEN DAT.BILL_TYPE IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN DAT.BILL_TYPE LIKE '%-%' AND AP.TYPE_OF_BILL BETWEEN STRTOK(DAT.BILL_TYPE,'-',1) AND STRTOK(DAT.BILL_TYPE,'-',2) THEN 1 WHEN AP.TYPE_OF_BILL = DAT.BILL_TYPE THEN 1 else 0 END)  AS BILL_TYPE_RULE               
,MAX(CASE WHEN DAT.ATTENDING_PROV_NETWORK IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN DAT.ATTENDING_PROV_NETWORK = ALV.NET_AFFIL_LEVEL_C THEN 1 else 0  END)  AS ATTENDING_PROV_RULE              
,MAX(CASE WHEN DAT.REFERRING_PROV_NETWORK IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN DAT.REFERRING_PROV_NETWORK = RLV.NET_AFFIL_LEVEL_C THEN 1 else 0 END)  AS REFERRING_PROV_RULE               

FROM HCCLSC.AP_CLAIM AP       
INNER JOIN HCCLSC.CLM_MAP CLM1 ON AP.CLAIM_ID=CLM1.CID --AND CLM1.INTERNAL_ID in ('363137412',  '363149130')
INNER JOIN HCCLSC.CLARITY_VENDOR VEN ON AP.VENDOR_ID = VEN.VENDOR_ID             
INNER JOIN HCCLSC.VENDOR_TAX_ID VTIN ON AP.VENDOR_ID = VTIN.VENDOR_ID            
INNER JOIN KPBISC_GRP_NCAR.AUTH_EXCEPTIONS DAT ON VTIN.TAX_ID = DAT.VENDOR_TIN               
LEFT JOIN HCCLSC.AP_CLAIM_PX PX ON AP.CLAIM_ID = PX.CLAIM_ID       
LEFT JOIN HCCLSC.CLARITY_EAP EAP ON EAP.PROC_ID = PX.PROC_ID        
LEFT JOIN HCCLSC.EAF_MAP EAF ON AP.LOC_ID = EAF.CID             
LEFT JOIN HCCLSC.CLARITY_SER_NETAFF ALV ON AP.ATTEND_PROV_ID = ALV.PROV_ID AND ALV.LINE = 1       
LEFT JOIN HCCLSC.CLARITY_SER_NETAFF RLV ON AP.REF_PROV_ID = RLV.PROV_ID AND ALV.LINE = 1       

where   
TRUNC(AP.DATE_RECEIVED) BETWEEN sysdate-60 AND sysdate and

COALESCE(AP.WORKFLOW_C,0)=0   
and  AP.STATUS_C in (2, 4, 3)

GROUP BY AP.CLAIM_ID,CLM1.INTERNAL_ID, px.line,  DAT.VENDOR_GROUP

order by AP.CLAIM_ID    , px.line
)
```

Comment: I know this sounds trivial, but are you checking the results in the same session that you ran the code?  You don't have a COMMIT statement in the anonymous block you put in your question.  If you are checking from a different session (Some IDE's create a new session for each window), you won't see the newly inserted records.

Comment: @del That's not trivial. I was running from different tabs, but adding in a commit didn't work. Tried both adding a commit to the end of the proc itself as well as when executing the proc (begin proc; commit; end;), no dice.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the commit problem mentioned in the other answer, try running the elect statement on it's own, but wrapping the whole statement in a select count(*) from (your_statement);

This will tell you if your query is returning zero rows.

Comment: returns about 143k records, so its not that its loading 0 records. I'm concerned it has something to do with commits, but i've tried adding the commit both to the stored proc definition as well as when executing it, and neither seems to work.

However, just running "insert into table [select statement]" works just fine. I'm missing something.